# Dealing with Cyrillic alphabet used in place of Latin characters

Tags: utf-8, utf

We've recently had a user enter english text, but it appears to have been done on a computer set up for Cyrillic as some of the letters such as "a" are actually CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A, as opposed to LATIN SMALL LETTER A.

I thought that [normalising](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-29.html) would convert the Cyrillic to the Latin equivalent, but it does not (I guess that they are only equivalent in how they are displayed rather than their meaning).

Is this a common problem - user's who have computers setup for Cyrillic may be writing english, but with the Cyrillic alphabet instead?

What would be a safe way to spot this in general, and convert it appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

To detect Cyrillic just use Regex match [\p{IsCyrillic}]. A more generic approach would be to search for any characters which are non-Latin ones. 
Ones you've got a match, you'll need to replace the characters with their Latin equivalents.